# Como poner una varible en una funcion Beanshell de Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

tengo un problema con Beanshell de JMeter y es que quiero poner dentro de una funcion a la que llamo pero el problema es que no me lo consigue detectar en cambio si pongo un numero si:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien que me pueda ayudar ya que he estado buscando y no hay mucha información por internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu [preprocesador Beanshell](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) utiliza 
 `vars.put("randomNumSum",Integer.toString(Integer.valueOf(num)+2));` en lugar de `vars.put("randomNumSum",(Integer.valueOf(num)+2));`

Para más información sobre beanshell, puedes ir al siguiente enlace:

[Prueba lógica compleja con beanshell](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/06/4878/)

Comment: Hello @Rohit, thank you very much for your reply, but I would appreciate it if you could use the official language of the site, which is Spanish.

Comment: I have updated my answer using google translator :)

Comment: Muschas gracias! Igualmente al final opte por hacerlo mediante parametros y no variables, pero seguramente esto me ayudara en un futuro para otras pruebas futuras!